# Altium - Multple jumper component

Tags: altium

EDIT:
For some reason Altium stopped to synchronize the Schematic and PCB for the jumper footprints. I have to set the Pads net manually. With this, the jumper method works and the second pad is assigned to the correct net once the first pad has been set manually.
This is not nice and I am afraid of inconsistencys in Schematic/PCB, but it'll do for now! Any better solutions are highly appreciated.

---

I am currently creating a rigid-flex PCB in Altium 15.
As a "real" rigid-flex PCB is quite expensive, I'd like to create a rigid-only pcb panel that contains the rigid sections and use flexible SMD jumpers to connect them:

[image: Rigid-flex vs rigid with flex connector]

I still want to handle this PCB as one PCB in Altium.
Meaning: I dont want to seperate the nets on the different sections.

My idea was create a flex connector footprint of type Jumper, giving the same Jumper ID to the pads that will be connected with the flex jumper (see image below, pins 1 and 20: jumper ID 1, pins 2 and 19: jumper ID 2, ...):
[image: flex connector footprint]

Then, create a schematic symbol that is set to jumper as well and only put pins 1..10 on this (as pins 11..20 should be connected through the jumper ID).
[image]

However, Altium does not apply the same nets to the respective pins.
Do I have to put ALL the pins on the schematic? I thought the internal jumper ID would already connect these.
[image]
I dont want 2 pins that I simply connect to the same net, as Altiums design rule check will create "unrouted net constraint" errors between the jumper pads.

Any idea on how to do this properly?

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: I believe you would indeed need to add all of the pins (1-20) on the schematic and set the jumper ID on each pin in the schematic component to match its mating pin. This would treat the external flex as a jumper.

Comment: if you are comfortable with routing to the board edge, just blast a track over the cutout and suppress the warnings with a room over the cutout and a rule that only applies to the room for board edge clearance to copper.

Comment: Luke: I thought about this but .. the idea is not very appealing.

@DerStrom8 hm based on the altium online documentation:

"As mentioned above, there are 2 conditions that make a Jumper a Jumper:

* Both pads in the Jumper must have their Jumper ID set to the same, non-zero value. [...]
* The Jumper Component must have its Type set to Jumper. "

So I think setting the Jumper ID to the opposite pin number is not the solution, but I'll try it nontheless.

Comment: I'll be honest I don't think I've ever had to use the jumper utility in Altium, so I'm completely guessing at this point =P